# Twice differentiable function on the closed interval $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, rolles-theorem

I'm stuck on a problem in calculus right now and it sounds as following:

Let $f(x)$ be a twice differentiable function on the closed interval $[a,b]$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that the segment of the line that connects $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ intersects the graph $y=f(x)$ in a point $(c,f(c))$ where $c \in (a,b)$. Show that there exists at least one point $d \in (a,b)$ such that $f''(d)=0$.

I've tried multiple things, such as constructing some helping function $g(x)=f(x)-u(x)$ where $u(x)$ is the line that connects connects the points $a$ and $b$. I've also tried applying Rolle's theorem on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$, but realising that my calculus class haven't gotten that far, I can't use it trivially (i.e. without actually proving it, which is still a ways beyond my capabilities I'm afraid). So how would I go about solving this? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you cannot use Rolle's theorem, is that the case? I mean, the answer is really simple : the Lagrange mean value theorem on $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$ gives you two points $d \in (a,c)$ and $e \in (c,b)$, such that $f'(d)$ is the slope of the line joining $(a,f(a))$ and $(c,f(c))$, similarly for $f'(e)$. But the slopes are the same, so $f'(d) = f'(e)$, now can you see why there's a $q \in (d,e)$ such that $f''(q) = 0$? Use Rolle with $f'$.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I could've made that more clear. We are allowed to use the mean-value theorem (I do realise that Rolle's theorem is a special case of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point $x_1$ between $a$ and $c$, we have 
$$f'(x_1) = \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a} = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
by the mean value theorem. At some point $x_2$ between $c$ and $b$, we have
$$
f'(x_2) = \frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c} = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$
again by the mean value theorem.

What does Rolle's theorem say about the derivative of $f'$ (i.e. $f''$) on the interval $(x_1, x_2)$ in this case?

Comment: That since $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, there must exist some value such that $f'(value) = 0$, is that correct? In hindsight "value" might be vague.

Comment: @DerpyMcDerp You're missing a $'$ on all your $f$s. But otherwise, yeah.

Comment: Yes of course, a typo on my part. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DerpyMcDerp (And "value" isn't vague. It's not very common for variables to have names with more than one letter in them, but that doesn't mean it doesn't make sense. However, you problem statement seems to want you to use $d$ instead.)